# Possible to override the blocking of a package's (re-)installation after it has been required/loaded?

Tags: r, installation, package, overriding

### Actual question

Is it possible to override the blocking of a package's (re-)installation after it has been required/loaded?

I understand that blocking a "true" **re-installation** to the **same** library that the package was loaded from makes perfect sense once the package is in use. But my use case is a bit different

### Background

I like the idea of having a "sandbox library" to test own packages. Besides the package(s) to test, those sandbox libraries contain all base packages of a clean base R installation **plus** some contrib packages necessary in order for my whole package building and testing framework to work (e.g. `digest`, `stringr` etc.). However, my framework loads the latter packages from the standard lib and **then** needs to install them to the sandbox lib - which is blocked. Hence my question if it is possible to override this as I'm not really doing what people had in mind when implementing the block.

### Illustration

Specify paths to the two libraries

```
lib         <- file.path(R.home(), "library")
lib.sandbox <- file.path(tempdir(), "library")
```

Create sandbox library

```
dir.create(lib.sandbox, showWarnings=FALSE)
```

Install a package to the standard library and load it

```
install.packages("digest", lib=lib)
require("digest", lib.loc=lib)
```

Then also install it to the sandbox library

```
> install.packages("digest", lib=lib.sandbox)
Warning: package 'digest' is in use and will not be installed
```

My framework figures certain stuff out **after** certain packages that should also be installed to the sandbox lib are loaded, so I can't put the "install-to-sandbox-lib" step before the initial loading step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a general version of what you suggest in your answer. This will unload the package before installing and reload the package from the same location afterward.

```
install.packages.sandbox <- function(pkgs, lib, repos=getOption("repos"), ...) {
    if (is.null(repos)) 
        stop("Can't install from source. Need package name.")
    pkg.pos <- grep(pkgs, search())
    pkg.path <- searchpaths()[grep(pkgs, searchpaths())]
    in.use <- length(pkg.pos) > 0
    # detach
    if (in.use) do.call(detach, 
                  list(pkg.pos), 
                  envir=.GlobalEnv)
    # install
    utils::install.packages(pkgs, lib, repos, ...)
    # re-attach from original library location
    if (in.use) library(pkgs, 
                  character.only=TRUE, 
                  lib.loc=.libPaths()[sapply(.libPaths(), grepl, pkg.path)])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not what I was after conceptually, but a pragmatic workaround: detaching the package right before installing it

Specify paths to the two libraries

```
lib         <- file.path(R.home(), "library")
lib.sandbox <- file.path(tempdir(), "library")
```

Create sandbox library

```
dir.create(lib.sandbox, showWarnings=FALSE)
```

Install a package to the standard library and load it

```
install.packages("digest", lib=lib)
require("digest", lib.loc=lib)
```

Detach package

```
detach(package:digest)
```

Then also install it to the sandbox library

```
> install.packages("digest", lib=lib.sandbox)
trying URL 'http://cran.at.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/2.15/digest_0.5.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 79053 bytes (77 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 77 Kb

package 'digest' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\wwa418\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6XSVYq\downloaded_packages
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of the already mentioned search path altering approach, it may be worthwhile noting that this warning and behavior comes (at least as of R 3.6.2) from `utils:::.install.winbinary`, where the check against attached packages is made.

What we therefore can do alternatively to circumvent this issue is to instead of using the binary installation method, install the package from source:

```r
library(digest)
utils::install.packages("digest", lib = tempdir(), type = "source")
```

This of course comes with some potential caveats if the package requires compilation of C/C++/Fortran code, as written in `help("install.packages")` for Windows:

> Using packages with type = "source" always works provided the package
>   contains no C/C++/Fortran code that needs compilation. Otherwise, you
>   will need to have installed the Rtools collection as described in the
>   ‘R for Windows FAQ’ and you must have the PATH environment variable
>   set up as required by Rtools.
>
> ...